# Removing fake experience from my resume

Tags: job-search, job-change, careers, background-check, career-switch

I was searching for jobs for 6 months after I graduated.  I signed a contract with a consulting company for 12 months. But after joining, the company faked my resume and submitted me to clients.  Now they have sent me to provide services for a client who believes I have more experience than I actually do.  All is perfect with the client but the thought of fake resume is killing me. I want to get rid of it and move to another job.

Now when I apply to new jobs I have removed all the entries my company added to my resume. But if the new company does a background check, will I face a problem?  Should I explain my situation to the new recruiter?

Comment: Hey Crusher, welcome to The Workplace. If I were you, I'd *strongly* consider rewording your question title, as you don't want people to get the wrong idea before they even read your post. Good luck!

Comment: Are you still working with the consulting company or did you leave?  If you've left how long did you work there?  These are details that may matter for those trying to answer this question.

Comment: I am still working with the client of the consulting company for the past 6 months and I still have 6 months of contract left with the consulting company.

Comment: So the consulting company padded your resume with fake experience?

Comment: @DanPichelman That's right.

Comment: I am not certian how a company makes you go to work for someone else against your will.  Did they send some goons to pick you up for work every day while threatening your family should you refuse?

Comment: h1?  Just take it off, they only check what you tell them, they do not hunt down old resumes of yours.  If its on linkedin, or somewhere else public, that could be an issue.

Comment: @Chad Thats too threatening man ;) Just afraid of getting sued.

Comment: @Crusher did they threaten to sue you?  Why did they say they would?

Comment: @Chad Yes because I signed a contract for 12 months before I came to know about this.

Comment: That is not really forcing you to work against your will.  They convinced you to uphold an obligation you had agreed to.

Comment: @Crusher - If you don't mind, can you tell us how many years of REAL experience do you have ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would make sure that any new resume you send out (and do not use that consulting company again) is correct with your real experience. In general when people check backgrounds, they care about whether you were employed by who you said on their application you were employed by, doing the job you said you did, during the days you said you were there.

They might also check things like if you really had the degree you claimed and your credit history. They would not see any previous resumes you sent out in the past and would not be likely to ask any questions about them.

If by chance anyone does ever know (perhaps they saw your old resume), then explain that the current resume is correct and the other was changed without your permission and is inaccurate. Most of us have seen how unethical some recruiters are and would understand that.

Comment: Thanks! My real concern would be how the new HR would think of me saying it frankly. There might be chance that he/she might take it in a negative way.

Comment: And you may get hit by a bus when you're crossing the street @Crusher, that isn't a good reason to worry about it excessively since you can't control it. HLGEM is spot on -- send out correct information, and if it does come up, be honest and tell them that it was changed without your permission. There aren't really any other options.

Answer (score 8):

When a company does a back ground check they are going to check with your company about the type of employee you were and the type of work you performed at most, and more likely just did you actually work there and the dates.  They are not going to compare the resume you give them with the one you gave your previous employer.

It is even possible that your resume is not even on file at your current employer.  Once you passed your probation period, there is no value in retaining that information.  Many companies destroy the resume as soon as the on-boarding paper work is completed, and some even before.

What ever you do, do not bad mouth the consulting firm that placed you or the company you were placed with. And that includes mentioning that the consulting firm doctored your resume.  It just makes you look bad.  Be cordial and stick to the good parts of your relationship with both.

Comment: Good points - the OP is the victim of a strange set of circumstances so there's no reason to dig a deep hole.

Comment: @JeffO - It is not as uncommon as it should be.  There are many consulting companies that use those types of tactics. At least the doctored resume, and high pressure tactics to accept the offer.

Comment: This may be partially conflicting with the answer above: saying that your résumé was changed without your permission, and also not bad-mouthing the consulting firm. I guess the only difference is the first is saying when asked and the second is doing so on your own...

Comment: @cst1992 - That is exactly my point.  You can not say that they doctored your resume.  It is bad mouthing them, and it will be taken against you.  Honestly if you are in a position where you have to justify your resume being doctored you have already lost any chance at the position anyway.