# Company wants me back, but does not offer written counter offer

Tags: job-search, job-offer, new-job, ethics, india

Please go through the question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183399/manager-faked-my-experience-to-get-projects-from-a-client/183404?noredirect=1#comment600400_183404). Due to the reason mentioned in the link, coupled with some other reasons like no salary hike for a year despite handling multiple roles (development, team lead and client handling all by me), below industry level salary, delayed payments, etc., I decided to quit. And I handed my resignation via email 7 days before (i.e. 15 March 2022). The reason that I cited was that I wanted to go for higher studies (I didn't want to mention the real reason, otherwise, company would think I would bad-mouth them, or tell the client the truth).

Since I hid the real reason, the company wants me back. But the manager only stated verbally that he was going to increase my salary. No **written** counter offer. They have also not yet accepted my resignation nor decided my last working day

1. Is this considered as a valid trustworthy offer? While providing for counter offer, does the current company offer in writing?
2. What I mentioned in the question link given above, is that thing normal in the industry and I should re-consider my resignation ?

Comment: We can't know if the offer is valid, only your manager knows that.  We also can't know if you are making a mistake or not by quitting.

Comment: If you gave them a valid resignation, how can they decide not to accept?

Comment: @SolarMike Not sure. They haven't so far

Comment: @PeterM I know, but I want to know if this faking of resume to clients is normal, and if a counter offer from current company is to be in written mode?

Comment: Faking resumes to clients is not normal. If they are lying to their clients they are not trustworthy and they are likely lying to you as well. If you have a new job: move on and don't look back.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Although I wanted more money, I didn't quit only because of that. It was due to other serious reasons

Answer (score 10):

You have already stated that your manager has faked your resume to receive contracts from your client. I don't think you need any more proof to be vary of anything your manager suggests.

But there is more:

> ...coupled with some other reasons like no salary hike for a year despite handling multiple roles (development, team lead and client handling all by me), below industry level salary, delayed payments...

Therefore:

> Is this considered as a valid trustworthy offer?

Chances are very slim.

Comment: Even if it is a valid offer; do you really want to work for someone who only offers an already deserved raise when you concretely decide to quit? What kind of a tone will this set for your future career at this company?

Answer (score 5):

Couple of things here:

If the company has put you in compromises about ethics and you've decided to leave, why are you at all considering staying if you already know that management is inclined to lie?  The whole situation is sketchy. I wouldn't stay.

On the other hand, if you're seriously considering staying, you could do one of two things:

- (easiest) Prepare an email that outlines the terms of what the manager offered you verbally.  Send the email from your **personal** account, and request that the manager confirm the terms in the response.  Be specific on amounts of money, dates, your new job title, and responsibilities.
- (hardest) Request that the manager send you a written offer.

If this is important to you, you're going to need to be more proactive and not sit back guessing on the question of "why didn't he ____________?"  In business, it's not what you're worth, it's about what you can negotiate.

Comment: I wanted to use the increased salary as a proof to negotiate with other companies

Comment: Asish, it should be obvious by now that the only thing you will get from that company is a bit of lukewarm air. Your manager is a cheat, as you know. And what do cheats do? They cheat.